# If $Q_n \to Q$ strongly in $B(L^2)$, then is it true that $|Q_n| \to |Q|$ in some appropriate sense?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory

Let $Q, Q_n \in B(L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$ be self-adjoint, and $Q_n \to Q$ strongly in $B(L^2)$, that is, $Q_n f \to Q f$ in $L^2$ for all $f \in L^2$.
Then, $|Q_n| \to |Q|$ in some appropriate sense?

Observation.
$\||Q_n| f\|_2 = \|Q_n f\|_2 \to \|Q f\|_2$ for all $f \in L^2$. Therefore, for any $f\in L^2$, $(|Q_n| f)_n \subset L^2$ is bounded, and it has a subsequence $(|Q_{n(k)}| f)_k$ which weakly converges to some $g \in L^2$. I think that it is natural to expect $g=|Q|f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, if $Q,Q_n\in B(H)$ are self-adjoint and $Q_n\to Q$ strongly, then $f(Q_n)\to f(Q)$ strongly for any bounded continuous function $f$.

First note that multiplication is strongly continuous on bounded subsets of $B(H)$: If $S_\alpha\to S$ and $T_\alpha\to T$ strongly, then
$$
\|(S_\alpha T_\alpha-ST)\xi\|\leq \sup_\beta\|S_\beta\|\|(T_\alpha-T)\xi\|+\|(S_\alpha-S)T\xi\|\to 0.
$$
By induction, the continuity property from the first paragraph holds for monomials, and by linearity for arbitrary polynomials (note that $(Q_n)$ is bounded in $B(H)$ by the uniform boundedness principle).

Finally, if $f$ is an arbitrary continuous function on a compact set containing $\sigma(Q_n)$, $\sigma(Q)$, then there exists a sequence of polynomials $(p_k)$ such that $p_k\to f$ uniformly by the Stone-Weierstraß theorem. It follows that
\begin{align*}
\|(f(Q_n)-f(Q))\xi\|&\leq \|(f-p_k)(Q_n)\xi\|+\|(p_k(Q_n)-p_k(Q))\xi\|+\|(p_k-f)(Q)\xi\|\\
&\leq 2\|f-p_k\|_\infty+\|(p_k(Q_n)-p_k(Q))\xi\|.
\end{align*}
As discussed above, the second summand goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, while the first summand converges to zero as $k\to\infty$ as a consequence of the uniform convergence of $(p_k)$ to $f$.